# Mysql JSON update key value

Tags: json, sql-update, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE `campus_tb` (
 `campus_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `campus_dataJSON` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL CHECK (json_valid(`campus_dataJSON`)),
 PRIMARY KEY (`campus_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

INSERT INTO `campus_tb`( `campus_dataJSON`) VALUES ( '[
                          {"id":"100","name":"James","age":"17","course":"IT"},
                          {"id":"101","name":"Eric","age":"19","course":"CS"},
                          {"id":"102","name":"Julie","age":"21"}]')




+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| campus_id          |  campus_dataJSON                                          | 
+--------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 1                  |  [
                     |     {"id":"100","name":"James","age":"17","course":"IT"},
                     |     {"id":"101","name":"Eric","age":"19","course":"CS"},
                     |     {"id":"102","name":"Julie","age":"21"}
                     |
                     |  ] 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
| 2                  |  [
                     |     {"id":"34","name":"Mimi","age":"18","course":"IT"},
                     |     {"id":"35","name":"Jose","age":"20","course":"CS"},
                     |     {"id":"36","name":"Ken","age":"24"}
                     |
                     |  ]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Am using MariaDB 10.4**

1. MySql query UPDATE the details for *Julie* of `campus_id = 1` to add a ***"course"*** for her to become like:

   {"id":"102","name":"Julie","age":"21","course":"MASCOM"},
2. Mysql Query to UPDATE  from **"Eric"** to **"Erick"** with a "k" at the end

I have tried so far:

```
UPDATE `campus_tb` 
SET `campus_dataJSON` = JSON_SET (`campus_dataJSON`, TRIM( '"' FROM JSON_SEARCH(`campus_dataJSON`,'one','Julie')),'MASCOM') 
WHERE 
    `campus_id` = 1 AND 
    JSON_EXTRACT(`campus_dataJSON`,'$.id') = '102';
```

This returns `0 rows affected`... I have heavily googled.

Comment: *Am using MYSQL VERSION 10.2* No such version. Look carefully.

Comment: *I have a table like:* Add CREATE TABLE & INSERT INTO scripts with this data.

Comment: ok noted for the Create table... doing it
As per the Mysql... the CPANEL says Version 10.2

Comment: You are probably using mariadb, not mysql. Json_set was added in v10.2.3 - do you have a later version? Pls provide the full error message or detail the unexpected behaviour! `Still not succeeded` is vague and thus does not tell us anything.

Comment: *As per the Mysql... the CPANEL says Version 10.2* Execute `SELECT VERSION();` and show the output.

Comment: `SELECT VERSION();` it actually returns `10.4.15-MariaDB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you should to use [JSON_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html) function. For example first question can be solved in next way:

```
update campus 
 set campus_data = json_set(
   campus_data, '$[2].course', 'MASCOM')
 where campus_id = 1;
```

Test on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=cc53705ecd5ddceb01d09670da001f9e&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)

In case when you don't know JSON path you can use [JSON_SEARCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html) & [JSON_UNQUOTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html) like:

```
update campus 
 set campus_data = json_set(
   campus_data, 
   json_unquote(json_search(campus_data, 'one', 'Eric')), 
   'Erick'
 )
 where campus_id = 1;
```

Fiddle [here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=8c74b670c4ab7ce06f0996f5f30dec7b&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)

Comment: Tested and working .... Just one thing this means I should know the `$[N]` index all the times.... What if the campus gets over 1000 students...is there away of UPDATING based on `"id"` ex: Juie's `id` is `102`??

Comment: PERFECT.... Exactly what I wanted.... Thank you very much. ACCEPTED